# Fast Finding optimum subset count that union of them equal to base set

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm

I have base set that has 4,000,000 member and there is 50 subset from base set

I want select optimum count of subset that union of them equal to my base set

if with two subset  can I do this its answer else I must find 3 subset and ....

Speed is my issue to solving this problem

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: @Nolonor no its not homewrok I should solve this speed problem issue in my c# program

Comment: -1 for not showing what you've tried.

Comment: If I understand that correctly, that's the Set Cover Problem, which is NP-complete. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem
Is an approximation acceptable?

Comment: @harold Thank you very much you point me to the correct answer and saved my time.please post Answer and i'll Mark it as answer

Comment: I Have a growing set that gorws upto 4,000,000 member but subsets always is 50.With your answer i choose greedy set cover algorithem and use pointer for each member and a flag for when i Find a large subset I set all member flag to used then with this trick I make other subset smaller with no repated member of pervius subest so I can easily select next large subset if I need

Comment: Ok very good, I don't think I can add anything relevant to that

Comment: ok please post an answer and thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you describe is an NP-Complete problem known as the [Set Cover Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem), for which various algorithms (exact or approximating) are known.